# REST Response from AWS Lambda function blocked by CORS policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, cors, aws-amplify

I enabled CORS support for the lambda using the API Gateway approach as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html).

I tested the API using the method documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-test-cors.html). The test was successful. Here are the results. Notice that `access-control-allow-origin` is enabled:

[image]

However, when I send the request from Javascript, I get the following error in my browser saying the origin `has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

For completeness, here is the JS request code:

[image]

... and the lambda function

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return the access control headers as part of the POST response.

```
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://www.example.com",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
};
```

Check Enabling CORS support for Lambda or HTTP proxy integrations in  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: I don't understand.  If that is the case, then why did I get the proper headers in my `curl` response (see above)?  That was set in the API Gateway, so why modify the lambda itself? Puzzled.